# I am obliged to format to build a Raid 5 array?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, raid-5

I have four identical Western Digital Elements 2TB which are all about 70 to 85% full.

I would like to create a RAID 5 array by removing all the hard drives from the external boxes and by putting them onto a raid card in my PC.

My question is: can I avoid formatting the drives and create the RAID 5 array without cloning or backuping the data?

I have no restriction on the operating system, Raid Controller, Software and time it will require if obviously it can be done in some way.

Also please consider that I can free the space of one disk at the maximum for needed parity.

Thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend you choose something other than Raid 5. Raid 6 or Raid 1+0 would be a lot safer.

Comment: Could you please suggest to me what are the better options considering that we are talking about 4 disks of 2TB. Also consider that I can find a way to free up to a maximum of 2TB over the 8TB total.

Comment: Is your question, 'can you set up a RAID5 and keep the existing data on your hard drives'? Or is it, 'can you set up a RAID5 without formatting the drives beforehand, on the understanding that you'll lose all of your data'?

Comment: I would like to keep the existing data on them because I do not have enough space to move it all elsewhere. I can move only about 2TBs over the total of 8TB.

Comment: @mstation I gave you the better options. Raid 6 or Raid 1+0. Both would grant you 4TB of space, but raid 1+0 will give you better read speeds.